# Some RewriteRule stopped working when upgrading Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I upgraded Apache from 2.2.14 to 2.4.7 on my server and some .htaccess RewriteRule has stop working

```
#this rule isn't working
RewriteRule ^places/create?$ ./create-place.php

#this rules are working
RewriteRule ^places/create/artist ./create-place-artist.php
RewriteRule ^places/create/location ./create-place-location.php
RewriteRule ^places/create/others ./create-place-others.php
```

Any idea about how could I update them?

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't tell from which version you upgraded and to what version, and you didn't tell what is not working.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Sorry, I edited it

Comment: What should your rule do ? It redirects `/places/creat` and `/places/create` to `/create-place.php`

Comment: @LorenzMeyer It should load create-place.php when entering domain.com/places/create but it shows error 404 because places/create.php doesn't exist

Comment: Why do you have that `?` ? What do you expect it to mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `?` is not at it's place in `^places/create?$`. `e?` means with `e` or without `e`.

Put it simply like the other rules that work:

```
RewriteRule ^places/create ./create-place.php
```

And you need to change the order. The more specific must be placed first :

```
RewriteRule ^places/create/artist ./create-place-artist.php
RewriteRule ^places/create/location ./create-place-location.php
RewriteRule ^places/create/others ./create-place-others.php
RewriteRule ^places/create ./create-place.php
```

Comment: Thanks! Now /places/create works but /places/create/artist and the other two doesn't work